# Setting a background image for only one tabItem in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on a shinydashboard, and I want to create a title page that will have a background image and a title. I was using `setBackgroundImage()`, but that made every `tabItem` have the image background. I only want the first `tabItem` to have the selected image background. How do I do this?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)


convertMenuItem <- function(mi, tabName) {
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-toggle'] = "tab"
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-value'] = tabName
  mi
}

star<- "\U2605"

panelES <- tagList(wellPanel(h2(strong("Elementary School")),p(star,star,star), style = "text-align: center;",style = "font-size:70px;"))
panelMS<- tagList(wellPanel(h2(strong("Middle School")),p(star,star,star), style = "text-align: center;",style = "font-size:70px;"))
panelHS<- tagList(wellPanel(h2(strong("Secondary School")),p(star,star,star), style = "text-align: center;",style = "font-size:70px;"))
panelU<- tagList(wellPanel(h2(strong("Postsecondary School")),p(star,star,star), style = "text-align: center;",style = "font-size:70px;"))


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "DEI Dashboard")

sideboard <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Title Page", tabName = "Title_Page"),tabName = "Title_Page"),
  convertMenuItem(
  menuItem("Overview", tabName = "Home_Page"),tabName = "Home_Page"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Elementary School", tabName = "es"),tabName = "es"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Middle School", tabName = "ms"),tabName = "ms"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Secondary School", tabName = "hs"),tabName = "hs"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Higher Education", tabName = "u"),tabName = "u"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Employment", tabName = "employment"),tabName = "employment"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Retention & Progressoin", tabName = "rp"),tabName = "rp"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Leadership", tabName = "leadership"),tabName = "leadership"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Venture Capital", tabName = "vc"),tabName = "vc"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Economic Impact", tabName = "ei"),tabName = "ei"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Recognition", tabName = "recognition"),tabName = "recognition"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("About", tabName = "about"),tabName = "about"),
  convertMenuItem(
    menuItem("Data & Sources", tabName = "ds"),tabName = "ds")
  
  ))

body <- dashboardBody(tabItems(
   tabItem(
    tabName = "Title_Page",
    setBackgroundImage(
      src = "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/dramatic-sunset-downtown-chicago-picture-id1204331594",
      shinydashboard = TRUE)),
    
    tabItem(
    tabName = "Home_Page",
    fluidPage(fluidRow(column(3,panelES),column(3,panelMS),column(3,panelHS),column(3,panelU)
                       )
              )
              )
 
    )
  )
  



ui <- dashboardPage(header,
                    sideboard,
                    body)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
}
```

**My codes output**
[Title Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAg99.jpg)
[The other pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAg99.jpg)

**Desired Output**
[Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAg99.jpg)
[other pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8dNI.png)

Comment: The `setBackgrounImage()` function sets the image to the `.content-wrapper` class, which it's a `div` that wraps ALL the tabs. This functions does not have the ability to set a background image for an individual tab.

Comment: @guasi, do you know of any alternative to only include a background for one background?

Comment: I don't. Shiny is based on divs within a single page. As you navigate, you see different divs show or hide. The tab divs do not cover the entire content area, they have margins and padding.  I haven't seen any packages that would set a background to the entire content area for only the active div, but I suspect a custom solution could be build with css/js. Not sure.

Comment: BTW you can easily set the background-image of a section using `tags$style('div#id {background-image: url( .. );}` but it would not cover the entire content area, just the tab box.